# TypeError: string indices must be integers When Checking array with dictionaries

Tags: python, arrays, django, dictionary

When checking if a key with certain value exist, I get a Type Error: string indices must be integers.

```
if not any(dObj["date"] == wholeDay for dObj in userPunchCard.clock):
  status = "Clock In"
  content = {
    "name" : user.name,
    "title" : user.title,
    "status" : status
  }
```

This is the db for userPunchCard

```
class StaffMember(models.Models):
  name = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
  title = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
  email = models.ChardField(max_length = 255)
  password = models.ChardField(max_length = 255)
  created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
  updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)
  objects = UserManager()
class PunchCard(models.Model):
  clock = models.CharField(max_length = 9999)
  employee = models.ForeignKey(StaffMember, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

I'm positive that userPunchCard.clock is indeed an array with at least one dictionary present because of this code.

```
if userPunchCard.clock is None:
 print ("if was hit in dashboard")

else:
 if not any(dObj["date"] == wholeDay for dObj in userPunchCard.clock:
status = "Clock In"
content = {
  "name" : user.name,
  "title" : user.title,
  "status" : status
}
```

When Creating a Django db table, the table will have null when empty and None works for me all the time to check for it. So the else in this code is running instead of the if. Also, when a user does clock in, this is the code that runs for a request.

```
userPunchCard.clock = []
newClockIn = {
  "date" : wholeDay,
  "clockIn" : standardTime,
  "clockOut" : None,
  "timeSpent" : None,
  "points" : None,
  "desc: None
}
userPunchCard.clock.append(newClockIn)
userPunchCard.save()
```

I was sure I was checking it correctly.

Comment: a `.clock` is not a list or dictionary, it is a string. If you iterate over it, you iterate over the characters (which are strings too), so you can indeed not use `dObj["date"]`.

Comment: Do you aim to store JSON blobs in `clock`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer**: you might want to make `clock` a `JSONField`.

The `PunchCard` model has a `CharField` as `clock`, so that means that strings are stored in that field. As a result, your `userPunchCard.clock` will return a string. If you then iterate over that string, you iterate over the characters, which are strings as well. So in that case `dObj` is a string, and hence `dObj["date"]` will indeed raise an error.

You might want to use a [**`JSONField`** field [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#django.contrib.postgres.fields.JSONField) instead, as provided by the [**`django-jsonfield`** package [PyPi]](https://pypi.org/project/django-jsonfield/). In most databases (except PostgreSQL for example), this is still internally stored as a `CharField`, but Django will automatically encode and decode the objects to their JSON counterpart. So a `JSONField` is capable to store lists, dictionaries, strings, integers, etc.

For example:

```
from jsonfield import JSONField

class PunchCard(models.Model):
    clock = JsonField(default=list)
    employee = models.ForeignKey(StaffMember, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```